# Storing username/password in MySql from Java

Tags: java, mysql

I am creating a register and login page for a Java GUI, where the username and password will be created in the GUI and then stored in a MySQL table.  The  relevant code is -

```
    passL = new JPasswordField();
    userNameT = new JTextField();

    //Set up everything else


    submitB = new JButton("click to submit");
    frame.add(submitB);
    submitB.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            try {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                Connection con = GetConnection.getConnectionInstance();
                PreparedStatement statement1 = con
                        .prepareStatement("INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES ("
                                + Integer.parseInt(userNameT.getText())
                                + ",SHA1('" + passT.getPassword() + "'))");
                statement1.executeUpdate();
            } //Catches exceptions etc
```

The userNameT is a number, the password (passT) can be anything (haven't wrote constraints yet).

My question is that Eclipse is giving me a warning on getPassword - "Must explicitly convert the char[] to a String".  Is there a security problem with the way I am doing this?

Also do I need to explicitly change passT to be null or blank straight after copying this, or will Java do it automatically.

All advice welcome! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the type mismatch: "*getPassword*" returns a **char[]** that needs to be converted to a **String** to be concatenated in your query.

Java will take care of **garbage collecting** your objects once not used anymore, i.e. not referenced from anywhere so you should not have to worry.

Maybe the only security precaution you could take would be to **clear the array** returned by "*getPassword*".

Comment: Thanks, is there a safe method to convert into a string?

Answer (score 0):

One of the points of using a `PreparedStatement` is to protect against [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), however the way you're using it still leaves you vulnerable. Instead, you should consider hashing in Java and set a parameter value like this:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES (?, ?)";
PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
stmt.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(userNameT.getText()));
stmt.setString(2, DigestUtils.sha1Hex(String.valueOf(userPassT.getPassword())));
```

Comment: Thank you, but this leaves me with a depracated method, the getText on the password.  Should I be making the password from the chars?

Comment: I meant passT.getPassword()